# How to calculate circular standard deviation in Java?

Tags: java, statistics

I have found some information about mean and standard deviation of circular statistics. Namely, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_statistics)

However I am not clear how I can code this in Java.

For circular mean I have tried something like:

```
for double radian : radians then
    cos += Math.cos(radian)
    sin += Math.sin(radian)
next

atan2 = Math.atan2(cos, sin)

if atan2 < 0 then
    atan2 += 2 * PI
end if

mean = Math.toDegrees(atan2) % 360
```

This seems to give me a neat result, but for the standard deviation I am very unclear.

Any help would be appreciated.

Matt

Comment: Shouldn't you be finding the mean cosine and sine for all of the angles? (You are currently only finding the sum.)

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Jeffrey is right, you have to devide cos and sin by the number of values before taking the atan2!

And regarding the standard deviation: you might want to take a look in the following paper (CircStat: A MATLAB Toolbox for Circular Statistics, Journal of Statistical Software 2009) describing a matlab toolbox for circular statistics (for scientific research). Even if you dont know matlab the paper gives many of the underlying equations including the circular standard deviation.

http://kyb.mpg.de/fileadmin/user_upload/files/publications/attachments/J-Stat-Softw-2009-Berens_6037%5b0%5d.pdf

Cheers,

Cornelius